# How to disable Save As and Save buttons from ms word 2010 when word open using c#

Tags: c#, ms-word, document

How to disable Save As  and Save buttons from ms word 2010 when word open using c#.

Comment: Just as a side note, I've not used these buttons in years, I always use Ctrl + S and f12

Answer (score 2):

You need to add [Ribbon XML item](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa942866%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to the project.

Ribbon is tool to customize the user interface (UI) of Microsoft Office applications.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui" 
    onLoad="OnLoad" > 
    <commands> 
      <command idMso="FileSaveAs" enabled="false" />
      <command idMso="FileSave" enabled="false" />
    </commands> 
 </customUI>
```

Comment: thank you very much.would i need to install ribbon(xml) template on visual studio.

Comment: I created the office project to my solution and added ribbon xml with above code  .Could you tell me how to customize the this XML with office.

Comment: if there is detail information about disable save button, please share. i have same problem cannot disable it. tq